# CCTray - Change url of server

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, dashboard, cctray

I have CC.Net installed and configured so its extenally accessable to me.  The problem is in CCTray when I'm on the network, double clicking one of the projects tries to open the dashboard with the internal name in the url, which doesn't have the virtual directory.

Is there any way to configure this for the server?  I know about the per project setting, but I'd hate to have to configure this for every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it for the server.
Nevertheless, you can define a preprocessor constant [1] and refers to it in every project. For example :

```
<cb:define serverAdress="http://myserver/"/>
...
<project name="OneProject" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
  <webURL>$(serverAdresss)OneProject</webURL> 
...
```

[1] http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor